# Weird behavior with String#match() capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

**Problem:** I have a string, e.g.: `"to see to be to read"` and I'd like to capture the 3 verbs *without the "to "* prefix, in this case: `be`, `see` and `read`.

On Regex 101, I've tried [this really simple regex](http://regex101.com/r/zP8tU5) and it solved the problem:

**Regex**: `/to (\w+)/g`
**Result:** `['be', 'see', 'read']`

Just for curiosity, I've made [this another regex](http://regex101.com/r/yH3kZ6), using positive lookahead, and the results were the same.

**Regex**: `/(?=to \w+)\w+ (\w+)/g`
**Result:** `['be', 'see', 'read']`

Okay. Weird thing is: When I'm running this regex on **Browser Console** (either Chrome or Firefox), the results are different. The two following tries gives me the same results: all three groups *including* the `to` prefix.

```
> 'to be to see to read'.match(/to (\w+)/g)
  ["to be", "to see", "to read"]

> 'to be to see to read'.match(/(?=to \w+)\w+ (\w+)/g)
  ["to be", "to see", "to read"]
```

Am I missing something here or am I stepping on a bug?

**Disclaimer:** This is not homework, I'm just validating this for a bigger problem. I'm not a regex expert but know a thing or two about it.

**EDIT:** I think I was fooled by Regex101. The code sample it gave me showed the `String#match()` approach, but this function doesn't exclude regexp groups accordingly on the resulting groups. Looping over `RegExp#exec()` matches is the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to capture groups in Javascript is using `RegExp#exec` method in a while loop:

```
var re = /to (\w+)/g,
    matches = [],
    input = "to see to be to read";
while (match = re.exec(input))
   matches.push(match[1]);

console.log(matches);
//=> ["see", "be", "read"]
```

Comment: Hmmm... I see. So I think what's left on the question is: Why isn't `String#match()` working as expected?

Comment: It is working as expected, it's just returning the substring that satisfies the match. Like anubhava said, `.exec()` method is the way you retrieve capture groups.

Comment: @EvertonAgner: `String#match` doesn't return all the captured groups like `preg_match_all` of PHP. See this Q&A also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex

Comment: Oh I see, I was relying on that. Thanks!